# remove certain prefix in every word separate by delimiter

Tags: regex, sed

How to remove certain prefix in every word separate by space? which I want to remove the prefix of `abc` and `def` from the beginning of the string. I have the sed statement which make it so long. Don't know if can make it shorter and simplier

```
Sed: sed -e 's/, /,/g' -e 's/'.yaml$'//g' -e 's/^abc_//g' -e 's/^def_//g' -e 's/,abc_/,/g' -e 's/,def_/,/g'

Input: abc_mscp_def.yaml_v1, def_mscp_abc.yaml_v2, abc_mscp_abc.yaml_v2, def_mscp_def.yaml_v2

Output: mscp_def_v1,mscp_abc_v2,mscp_abc_v2,mscp_def_v2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -E 's/(^|,) ?(abc|def)_|(,) |\.yaml/\1\3/g'
```

See the online demo:

```
s="abc_mscp_def.yaml_v1, def_mscp_abc.yaml_v2, abc_mscp_abc.yaml_v2, def_mscp_def.yaml_v2"
sed -E 's/(^|,) ?(abc|def)_|(,) |\.yaml/\1\3/g' <<< "$s"
# => mscp_def_v1,mscp_abc_v2,mscp_abc_v2,mscp_def_v2
```

**Details**

- `-E` option enables POSIX ERE syntax and alternation
- `(^|,) ?(abc|def)_|(,) |\.yaml` - matches:

  - `(^|,) ?(abc|def)_` - Group 1: start of string or comma, then an optional space, and then Group 2: either `abc` or `def`
  - `|` - or
  - `(,)`  - Group 3: a comma, and then a space
  - `|` - or
  - `\.yaml` - `.yaml` substring.

The replacement is `\1\3`, i.e. the values of Group 1 and 3 concatenated.

Comment: This may have unintended consequences i.e. false positives because the alternation is disjoint e.g. replace `abc` with `xyz` on the first string and review the result. Perhaps `sed -E 's/\b((abc|def)[^.]*)\.yaml/\1/g' file` is what you meant?

Comment: @potong I only shrank the current sed solution to a single command. The alternation works as required. A `sed -E 's/(^|(,) )((abc|def)_)?|\.yaml/\2/g'` is [also possible](https://ideone.com/dOwssw). `\b` word boundary may overmatch, OP only need to start matching at the start of the string or after comma.